# Cant figure out why using overloaded comparison operator is calling a copy constructor before execution

Tags: c++, comparison, operator-overloading, copy-constructor

As an assignment for my programming class, I'm writing a class definition for floats and dynamic memory allocation.  We are to build a class and use a test driver main program that runs it and tells us if our code is working or not.  My code for the class is FAR from being done, but this issue is driving my crazy and I can't figure it out.  Whenever the overloaded == operator is called, my copy constructor is also being called.  My last post, I got a lot of negative comments for posting too long of code, so I'm doing my best to only post the code needed to see the issues.

Here's my specification:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctype.h>

using namespace std;

class MyFloat
{
    enum {DefaultSizeTen=10};
    char *Number;

    int NumberOfDigits;
    int MaxNumberOfDigits;

public:

    ~MyFloat();//destructor

    MyFloat(const MyFloat & RHS);
    MyFloat();      //default constructor
    MyFloat(unsigned int Input); //create any length of MyFloat

    int Digits();
    int MaxDigits();

    MyFloat operator= (const char Input[]);


    int operator== (MyFloat x);

    MyFloat operator+ (MyFloat x);
    int operator> (MyFloat x);
    int operator< (MyFloat x);

    friend ostream& operator<< (ostream &Out, const MyFloat & X);
    friend istream& operator>> (istream &In, MyFloat & X);

};
```

In the test driver, this is the function using the overloaded == operator:

```
void TestComparison()
{
    MyFloat A, B, Sum;


    cout << "\n\n== == == == ==  Testing \"== \" for MyFloat  == == == == == \n\n";

    cout << "MyFloat variables have maximum length of " << A.MaxDigits() << endl;
    do
    {
        cout << "\nEnter A  ==> ";
        cin  >> A;
        cout << "\nEnter B  ==> ";
        cin  >>  B;

        cout << "\n (A == B) is " << ((A == B) ? "TRUE " : "FALSE ") << endl;


    }
    while ( SpaceBarToContinue() );
}
```

It is at THIS LINE `cout << "\n (A == B) is " << ((A == B) ? "TRUE " : "FALSE ") << ends;`that I'm having my issue.  Before the overloaded comparison operator is being called, the RHS is being sent into the copy constructor function, along with another variable, one that I can't figure out where its coming from (coming into the copy constructor as *this).  Here's the copy constructor:

```
MyFloat::MyFloat(const MyFloat & RHS)
{
    MaxNumberOfDigits=RHS.MaxNumberOfDigits;
    NumberOfDigits=RHS.NumberOfDigits;

    Number = new (nothrow) char[RHS.NumberOfDigits+1]; //+1 for overflow

    if (Number != NULL)
    {
        for (int i=0; i<=RHS.NumberOfDigits-1; ++i)
        {
            Number[i]=RHS.Number[i];
        }
    }

    else
        NumberOfDigits=0;
}
```

I don't know if this is enough information, but I got some negative feedback for posting too long of code last time, so I trimmed this down a bunch.

Comment: I'm just confused as why the copy constructor is even being invoked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Cant figure out why using overloaded comparison operator is calling a copy constructor before execution

You are passing the argument by value.

```
int operator== (MyFloat x);
```

Change it to a more idiomatic form:

1. Change the return type to `bool`.
2. Make the argument a `const&`.
3. Make the member function a `const` member function.

```
bool operator==(MyFloat const& x) const;
```

Comment: OH wow... I never even thought of that.  The fact its entering the overloaded function because I'm passing by value, so a copy is being made.  Wow, I feel entirely silly.  This assignment has my mind so screwed up, I'm not remembering the basics.  Thanks a ton.

Comment: @joe_04_04, don't feel too bad. Most of us have gone through such growing pains :)

Comment: @joe_04_04 - many years ago one of the leading experts in C++ asked me to figure out why his program was crashing. Turned out he had written a copy constructor that took its argument by value. Calling it meant copying the argument, which called the copy constructor, which needed the argument by value, so it called the copy constructor, etc.

Comment: Very Interesting!  Yes, it's silly, because I know the difference between value and reference passing, but because my head was so deep in the assignment, I had no idea why the copy constructor was being called.  I wasn't declaring a new object with an object with an assignment operator, I was so confused!  Makes perfect sense now that's it's brought to my attention.